# "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" Encountered in my oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

```
      SELECT TITLE, CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SUM((COST-RETAIL)/COST)*100), '100'), '%') 
      AS "Markup"
      FROM BOOKS
      GROUP BY TITLE;
```

::THE GOAL::
I'm trying to calculate the mark-up for my products (books).

::ZE PROBLEM::
When I try to run the stated SQL, I get the error

> *ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected*

In advance I thank you for any and all input on my issue.

Comment: Hint:  you have four left parentheses, and five right parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are not balanced I count 4 left and 5 right. This error usually happens when there is a formatting error that prevents the FROM clause from being reached (missing/extra comma, unbalanced bracket, etc)

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT TITLE, TO_CHAR( SUM( COST-RETAIL )/ SUM( COST )) || '%'
      AS "Markup"
      FROM BOOKS
      GROUP BY TITLE;
```

Comment: All is solved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra right parentheses and here is what it should look like.

```
SELECT TITLE, CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SUM((COST-RETAIL/COST)*100), '100'), '%') 
AS "Markup"
FROM BOOKS
GROUP BY TITLE;
```

Comment: not sure the math is right...

Comment: @Randy I don't look at the math, just fixed the issue that was asked about.